# How do I filter the rows of a large table based on the comparison of two of its columns?

Tags: python, filtering

I have a large table with informations about buildings. In 56.267 rows sets of data about a specific room are represented. Those rows are identified by their Room-ID and Building-ID.
And there are duplicate Building-IDs shown in the large table, because each building/Building-ID has several rooms/Room-IDs.

Another column, or if you want table, shows 607 specific Building-IDs. In the large table, where there are more than 607 Building-IDs shown, I only want to display those 607 Building-IDs. Of those I also want to keep duplicates (see table_A column "A_new" entries 4 and 4)
So this specific column serves sort of as a reference column and I want to filter my large table based on that.

I recreated a similar dataset as follows where table_A is my large table that I want to filter and table_B represents the reference column/table:

```
table_A = {
    'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5],
    'more stuff': ["yes", 10, 100, 150, 200, 250],
    'even_more stuff': ["no", 10, 50, 100, 200, 250],
    'B': [2,4]}
table_B = {
    'B': [2, 4]}
```

I also included "B" as a column within table_A just in case it needs to be in there as a column as well.

Then I tried to use the method groupby and defined the following Dataframes:

```
table_A_df = pd.DataFrame(table_A, columns=['A','more stuff','even_more stuff','B'])
table_B_df = pd.DataFrame(table_B, columns=['B'])
```

What I am aiming at, is a table as follows:

```
table_A_filtered = {
    'A_new': [2, 4, 4],
    'more stuff': [10, 150, 200],
    'even_more stuff': [10, 100, 200]}
```

By finally getting it via:

```
table_A_filtered = table_A_df.groupby(["B"])
```

It did not work though because the reference column "B" is suppose to be as long as the other columns.
The error messages were stating
"ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length" and "KeyError: 'B'"

However I expected to be able to filter according to the entries of column "B" and empty entries as no issue.

I'd be glad to receive help to find a solution. Maybe my approach with groupby is not even a good start.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could just use the [`isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) method:

```
import pandas as pd

table_A = {
    'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5],
    'more stuff': ["yes", 10, 100, 150, 200, 250],
    'even_more stuff': ["no", 10, 50, 100, 200, 250],
}
table_B = {'B': [2, 4]}
table_A_df = pd.DataFrame(table_A,
                          columns=['A', 'more stuff', 'even_more stuff'])
table_B_df = pd.DataFrame(table_B, columns=['B'])
table_A_filtered = table_A_df[table_A_df['A'].isin(table_B_df['B'])]
table_A_filtered = table_A_filtered.rename(columns={'A': 'A_new'})
print(table_A_filtered)
```

**Output:**

```
   A_new more stuff even_more stuff
1      2         10              10
3      4        150             100
4      4        200             200
```

Comment: Your idea was an elegant solution to my problem. Thank you very much for your help. Also thank you for your quick response. Very much appreciated!